# Backup-SPFarm not respecting ErrorActionPreference

Tags: powershell, backup, error-handling

I'm trying to setup a script in Jenkins to backup my SharePoint server. The problem I'm encountering is that it Backup-SPFarm is not correctly returning an error. So my $ErrorActionPreference is being ignored.

My script looks like:

```
Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
# $backUpDir=New-Item -Type Directory -Path d:\backups\SharePoint\$Env:BUILD_ID
# Backup-SPFarm -BackupMethod Full -Directory $backUpDir -Verbose
# Get-Content foo
Backup-SPFarm -BackupMethod Full -Directory d:\backups\bogus -Verbose
```

The result I'm getting looks like this:

```
Building in workspace D:\Alfred\jobs\Maintenance-Backup-SharePoint\workspace
[workspace] $ powershell.exe "& 'D:\Tomcat 7.0\temp\hudson3082553469596846563.ps1'"
VERBOSE: Leaving BeginProcessing Method of Backup-SPFarm.
VERBOSE: Performing operation "Backup-SPFarm" on Target "VA01DJNKCIS001".
Backup-SPFarm : Directory d:\backups\unknown does not exist or the SQL Server s
ervice account and the NT SERVICE\Tomcat7 service account do not have permissio
n to read or write to the backup folder. Specify a different directory or ensur
e that the SharePoint Timer service and Microsoft SQL Server service accounts h
ave Full Control permission on both the file share and the underlying folder.
At D:\Tomcat 7.0\temp\hudson3082553469596846563.ps1:5 char:14
+ Backup-SPFarm <<<<  -BackupMethod Full -Directory d:\backups\unknown -Verbose
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...mdletBackupFarm: 
   SPCmdletBackupFarm) [Backup-SPFarm], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletBackupFa 
   rm

VERBOSE: Leaving ProcessRecord Method of Backup-SPFarm.
VERBOSE: Leaving EndProcessing Method of Backup-SPFarm.
Finished: SUCCESS
```

When I was expecting to see something like this:

```
Building in workspace D:\Alfred\jobs\Maintenance-Backup-SharePoint\workspace
[workspace] $ powershell.exe "& 'D:\Tomcat 7.0\temp\hudson9060264468839525852.ps1'"
Get-Content : Cannot find path 'D:\Alfred\jobs\Maintenance-Backup-SharePoint\wo
rkspace\foo' because it does not exist.
At D:\Tomcat 7.0\temp\hudson9060264468839525852.ps1:3 char:12
+ Get-Content <<<<  foo
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (D:\Alfred\jobs\...t\workspace\f 
   oo:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCo 
   ntentCommand

Build step 'Windows PowerShell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

when given:

```
Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
# $backUpDir=New-Item -Type Directory -Path d:\backups\SharePoint\$Env:BUILD_ID
# Backup-SPFarm -BackupMethod Full -Directory $backUpDir -Verbose
Get-Content foo
# Backup-SPFarm -BackupMethod Full -Directory d:\backups\bogus -Verbose
```

Is there a return value from Backup-SPFarm that I can check? How do I check it?

Update: $LastExitCode seems to be blank when I add:

```
Write-Host $LastExitCode
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the `-Verbose` parameter? I have found that `-Verbose` seems to override `$ErrorActionPreference` for some reason ([possibly a bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/657494)). This is not just specific to Sharepoint commands.

You can also combine `-Verbose -ErrorAction "Stop"`.